# Distributing cells in column B over index in column A - included image for further clarification

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formula

I've been trying to get this done for way too long now, I can't figure out a way to automate this.
Underneath the question is an image to further show you what I mean. Left side of the image being what I have now and the right side being what I need.

I want to 'match' two columns, placing one non-blank cell of (in this case) column G next to every non-blank cell of column F.
The intervals between the integers in column F is inconsistent and by definition unpredictable, so I'd think I would either have to detect and ignore blank cells or only target filled ones.

Essentially distributing the non-blank G cells over the non-blank F cells.

The file has thousands of lines which is why I need it to be automated, I do have Ku Tools if that's any use to figuring this out.

Could really use your help!!

Thanks in advance,

Hugo

To support my explanation:

[image]

Comment: Use `COUNT` and `INDEX` maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `J1`, try:

```
=IF(F1<>"",INDEX(G:G,COUNT(F$1:F1)),"")
```

Drag down.

Comment: Oh wow, I was overthinking this majorly..
Thank you so much, guess I've got a lot to learn!

Have a nice day :)